# In TypeScript, why is there a difference between typing tsc and tsc FILENAME

Tags: typescript

If I type tsc in my directory, I get the following error message:

```
src/temp.ts:3:24 - error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
```

But if I type tsc src/temp.ts in exactly the same directory with no code changes, my TypeScript compiles.

Why is there a difference between these two commands?

Comment: Can you post your `tsconfig.json`? The difference must be there, but we can't fully understand what is it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is a big difference in the settings used.

If you execute `tsc src/temp.ts` the compiler will compile the file specified with default settings.

If you execute `tsc` the compiler will pick-up the settings from `tsconfig.json`, basically equivalent to `tsc -p tsconfig.json`.

From the error probably your `tsconfig.json` sets `strict` or `noImplicitThis` to true, while the default for these is false. This is why you get an error with one but not the other.